# HTML Parsing gives no response

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, urllib2

I'm trying to parse a web page, and that's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

openurl = urllib2.urlopen("http://pastebin.com/archive/Python")
read = BeautifulSoup(openurl.read())
soup = BeautifulSoup(openurl)
x = soup.find('ul', {"class": "i_p0"})
sp = soup.findAll('a href')
for x in sp:
    print x
```

I really with I could be more specific but as the title says, it gives me no response. No errors, nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, omit the line `read = BeautifulSoup(openurl.read())`.

Also, the line `x = soup.find('ul', {"class": "i_p0"})` doesn't actually make any difference, because you are reusing `x` variable in the loop.

Also, `soup.findAll('a href')` doesn't find anything.

Also, instead of old-fashioned `findAll()`, there is a `find_all()` in BeautifulSoup4.

Here's the code with several alterations:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

openurl = urllib2.urlopen("http://pastebin.com/archive/Python")
soup = BeautifulSoup(openurl)
sp = soup.find_all('a')
for x in sp:
    print x['href']
```

This prints the values of `href` attribute of all links on the page.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I altered a couple of lines in your code and I do get a response, not sure if that is what you want though.

Here:

```
openurl = urllib2.urlopen("http://pastebin.com/archive/Python")
soup = BeautifulSoup(openurl.read()) # This is what you need to use for selecting elements
# soup = BeautifulSoup(openurl) # This is not needed
# x = soup.find('ul', {"class": "i_p0"}) # You don't seem to be making a use of this either
sp = soup.findAll('a')
for x in sp:
    print x.get('href') #This is to get the href
```

Hope this helps.